# Connection to MongoDb failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was trying to connect my mongodb with node server using command prompt.

I started mongodb my mongod --dbpath E:\node start\node\data 
Then I installed mongodb dependencies using npm install mongodb

I added some code into my app.js which is described below :

**app.js**

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb'); //acquiring mongodb native drivers
var mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:7000/myDatabase'; //connection url
mongoClient.connect(url, function(err,db){
  if(err){
    console.log('Unable to connect to mongodb server. Error :' , err);
  }
  else{
    console.log('Connection established to', url);
    db.close();
  }
});
```

when I ran app.js in command prompt, following error occured :

```
Unable to connect to mongodb server. Error :{[ MongoError : connect ECONNREFUSED] name : 'MongoError' , message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' }
```

I cannot understand what the problem is and what should I do next.

Comment: The mongodb port is not the default port

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB usually runs on port 27017, but you're trying to connect to port 7000. Try changing your `url` variable.

```
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase';
```

Answer (score 1):

You know mongoDB has their default port no 27017.
And You have written 7000.

So Try to Change port no to 27017.

ok !!!!!!!

Comment: I tried it with port 27017 but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The error says you do not have mongodb running. You should check if your mongodb is running or not. If its running then you should check on what port it is running on.

The default port for mongodb is `27017`. If you have not configured your mongodb to run on port `7000` then changing var `url = 'mongodb://localhost:7000/myDatabase';` to var `url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase';` will work for you.